# obtaining cursor from sqlite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I've tried to follow a tutorial on accessing sqlite databases on android and i've made it so far.

my code gets to "columns[] created" and then i get a null pointer exception...

I believe my database is populated but i have no way of really telling. can someone show me how to check? / get this working?

```
public Cursor getAnimalCursor() {
    System.out.println("in getAnimalCursor()");
    String[] columns = new String[] {"_id", "name"};
    System.out.println("columns[] created");
    Cursor c = myDataBase.query("animals", null,  null, null, null, null, null);
    System.out.println("cursor created");
    return c;
}
```

Comment: my other question on how to get the database imported is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18550724/trying-to-import-my-sqlite-database-into-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you have initialized myDataBase. It is the cause of null pointer exception.

Comment: Hi there, I've tried using the getReadableDatabase() method with rawQuery() and it is not picking up any of the tables so i think you may be right in me not initializing the database. I've tried to run the dbHelper.createDataBase() method before that one but still no luck. i think i'm going to find another tutorial to follow.

Comment: i suggest you take a look at sample NotePad code provided by google. If you download samples through sdk manager you can find it at \android-sdk\samples\android-16\NotePad . Content Provider is the new thing and it goes very well with loaders so take a look at that

Comment: Yeah i was looking at a tutorial on that (vogella) and the Content Providers did strike me as a possible solution...

Comment: Damnit. I completely forgot to call the initialisation method `myDbHelper.createDataBase();` and `myDbHelper.openDataBase();`  on the main activity. Must've skipped over it when i was reading the tutorial... Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

You are not selecting any columns

have you tried this?

```
Cursor c = myDataBase.query("animals", columns,  null, null, null, null, null);
```

**Edit:**

as Anirudha Agashe mention

I think the NPE occurs because he does not do `open()` the sql

Comment: passing null returns all available columns. He is getting null pointer exception which cant be resolved by what you are suggesting.

Comment: Yeah I tried that, I think that the database didn't load up properly or something...